# How to make that textbox lost focus in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have textBox.I begin write something in textbox,and it opens popup with listBox.When i select any item from listBox,textBox losts focus.How to make that listbox not to take focus,or how to get focused textbox?I use MVVM

Comment: What u r trying to do when the items in listbox is selected? Is it should appear in the textbox?

Comment: yes,i get some information and add this to textbox

Comment: Then after getting the information and assigning it to textbox.Text, set **textbox.Focus()**

Comment: If there is possibility i would do that,i use MVVM and cannot access to txtbox

Comment: u can set this in the listbox events u r using.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be just to [set focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) manually to the textbox whenever it loses the focus. Mind however that this may automatically close your popup, so you'll need to tweak it as well.

By the way, maybe you just need a [combobox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) instead? It's exactly a textbox with a drop-down list of choices.

(MVVM doesn't matter here, the problem is purely in the view.)

Comment: I saw at somewhere but couldnt remind where that in listbox can be changed property like this FocusManager.. next part i couldnt remind

Comment: @Javidan: Are you really sure you are not reinventing the combobox?

Comment: now changed to it,but it restore focus to last control when combobox closed?

Comment: @Javidan: Usually, when you open a combobox's dropdown, the focus is already on the combobox's textbox, so as soon as the dropdown is closed, the focus has to return to the textbox. Is this not the case for your code?

Comment: no,my textbox is apart from combobox.I tested now,it doesnt restore focus to textbox.If there is no possibility i will do like you said set manually

Comment: @Javidan: wait a minute, could you please post your XAML fragment? The textbox is a part of combobox anyway: a combobox _consists of_ a textbox and a popup with a list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5415/discussion-between-javidan-guliyev-and-vlad)